# Name of card game similar to crazy-8s or Uno

Tags: identify-this-game, uno, crazy8s

I would like to know if anyone on here has played or knows the name of a card game similar to hearts.

The object of the game is to get rid of all your cards. If a player doesn't have a card that is played, he can play any card just like hearts. In this game there's no points system.

When 2 players remain in the game, the player who has more cards than the player who has one remaining must play a lower card to extend the game. The cards are then laid out and the player with no cards must pick a card from pack of cards which have been played and pick a card lower than the other players cards to win. The other player obviously has to clear his cards.

You can also request to take another players cards.
I believe it is an Asian card game but wondered if it had an English name and if many people play it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add any more details? Is there a trump? What keeps you from getting rid of your cards?

Comment: it's a simple game really, if you keep getting hit that will stop you from getting rid of your cards as your cards will grow.

Comment: Sounds more like ***Uno*** or ***Crazy Eights*** than any *whist* variant I have ever played. These games are really in dramatically different game families, so I question whether the *hearts* tag/comparison is helping you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be a form of [Minnesota Whist](http://www.pagat.com/whist/minwhist.html).

Even if it is not, I'd suggst starting with a cassification resource like: [Pagat](http://www.pagat.com/whist/index.html) and seeing if anything else jogs your memory.

Comment: With the additional details, I don't think it's Minnesota Whist, but it still might be fun to try.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old but were by chance thinking of Tricked out hero?

Comment: Could you explain the features of Tricked Out Hero such that it matches what's being described?